# SequenceGenerator to SequenceStyleGenerator moving from hibernate 4.2 to 5

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, sequence-generators

I've recently upgraded my project to use hibernate 5 which was earlier using hibernate 4.2. We have database sequence with naming convention followed as "SEQ_PrimaryKeyName". In hibernate 4.2 we were using org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator to generate the sequence - the code looks like this -

```
public class PrimaryKeyGenerator extends IdentityGenerator implements      Configurable {

    private PrimaryKeyGenerator  pkGen;

    public PrimaryKeyGenerator  () {
        pkGen= new SequenceGenerator();
    }

    //configure sequence generator 
    public void configure(Type type, Properties params, Dialect Dialect) throws MappingException {
        if (pkGen instanceof Configurable) {
            String seqName = "SEQ_" + params.getProperty(PersistentIdentifierGenerator.PK);
            params.setProperty(SequenceGenerator.SEQUENCE, seqName);    
            ((Configurable)pkGen).configure(type, params, dialect);
        }
    }

    // Generate sequence
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object obj) throws HibernateException {
        return pkGen.generate(session, obj);
    }
}
```

SequenceGenerator is deprecated in hibernate 5 and as per javadoc it is recommended to use org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.

I modified my existing PrimaryKeyGenerator class to following

```
 public class PrimaryKeyGenerator extends IdentityGenerator implements Configurable {
     private PrimaryKeyGenerator pkGen;

     public PrimaryKeyGenerator() {
         pkGen = new SequenceStyleGenerator();
     }

    // implement the methods of SequenceStyleGenerator.java
    @Override
    public void configure(Type type, Properties params, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) throws MappingException {
        if (pkGen instanceof Configurable) {
            String seqName = "SEQ_" + params.getProperty(PersistentIdentifierGenerator.PK);
            params.setProperty(SequenceStyleGenerator.SEQUENCE_PARAM, seqName);
            ((Configurable) pkGen).configure(type, params, serviceRegistry);
        }
    }

    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object obj) throws HibernateException {

        // collect instance of org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database   
        Database db = MetadataExtractor.INSTANCE.getDatabase();
        (SequenceStyleGenerator)pkGen).registerExportables(db);
        return pkGen.generate(session, obj);
    }
}
```

With above changes sequence are getting generated properly. The one question I have is that Is it allright to call registerExportable() method before calling generate method ? I am not sure but it looks like registerExportable should be called only once and not every time time generate() method is called. If I don't make a call to registerExportable method explicitly I get following exception.

`"SequenceStyleGenerator`'s SequenceStructure was not properly initialized"

May be the way I am trying to use SequenceStyleGenerator is not correct.